# How to center content horizontally without overlapping items on the side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a view layout that is similar to iOS's UINavigationBar:

[image: UINavigationBar]

UINavigationBar has a title that is centered on the screen and optional navigation items (buttons) on either side. If the title is too wide to fit in the center, then it will be pushed to the side to avoid overlapping the navigation items.

Is such a layout possible in CSS alone *without* JavaScript?

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/km9sy2sk/) I created with some attempts to achieve this layout.

[image: Fiddle screenshot]

In the screenshot above, the layout is achieved by floating the red and blue buttons on either side, and setting the left and right margin of the yellow div to `auto`. The second row above is exactly what I want, but unfortunately I have to set an explicit width on the yellow div.

I also tried flexbox but it doesn't allow me to center the yellow div with respect to the container.

If there is no way to avoid using JavaScript in this situation, what would be the best way (most compatible with each browser) to achieve it?

Comment: did you have a look at css display:flex properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the `center` div exactly in the middle of `row` by using `position: absolute` irrespective of the position of left & right.

Also, provide `position: relative` to `left` & `right` with a higher `z-index` for them to appear above `center`.

Refer code:

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 18px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background-color: cyan;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.zero {
  width: 0px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 565px) {
  .absolute {
    left: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="center">center center center</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="center absolute">center center center</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="center zero">center center center</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When somebody downvotes a perfectly working answer without providing an explanation, it's just disrespectful to the effort of the guys helping out here.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't want the center div to overlap the left or right side just like the title in UINavigationBar doesn't overlap the Settings button.

Comment: You can use `media queries` to achieve what you want to do here. After a specific width of screen, you can align the center div. Check updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Place left/right columns with Absolute Positioning.

```
.left,
.right {
  position: absolute;
}
.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}
.center {
  padding: 0 200px; // Add indents so columns don't overlap its content.
}
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.left,
.right {
  position: absolute;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  background-color: cyan;
  right: 0;
}

.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 200px;
}

.fixed {
  width: 130px;
}

.zero {
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="center">center center center</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="center">center center center</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="center">center center center</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the 200px is hardcoded. I won't know the size of the left and right divs, I might have 10 buttons on the left and only 1 button on the right, and buttons might change dynamically.

Comment: @DecadeMoon In that case you will need some JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 0):

change floats to absolute positioning,
with "row" as their "anchor"

```
.row{
 position: relative
}

.left,
.right {
  position: absolute;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}
```